# Drop duplicate lists within a nested list value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe with nested lists as values in a column as follows:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'single_proj_name': [['jsfk'],['fhjk'],['ERRW'],['SJBAK']],
                              'single_item_list': [['ABC_123'],['DEF123'],['FAS324'],['HSJD123']],
                              'single_id':[[1234],[5678],[91011],[121314]],
                              'multi_proj_name':[['AAA','VVVV','SASD'],['QEWWQ','SFA','JKKK','fhjk'],['ERRW','TTTT'],['SJBAK','YYYY']],
                              'multi_item_list':[[['XYZAV','ADS23','ABC_123'],['XYZAV','ADS23','ABC_123']],['XYZAV','DEF123','ABC_123','SAJKF'],['QWER12','FAS324'],[['JFAJKA','HSJD123'],['JFAJKA','HSJD123']]],
                              'multi_id':[[[2167,2147,29481],[2167,2147,29481]],[2313,57567,2321,7898],[1123,8775],[[5237,43512],[5237,43512]]]})
```

As you can see above, in some columns, the same list is repeated twice or more.

So, I would like to remove the duplicated list and only retain one copy of the list.

I was trying something like the below:

```
for i, (single, multi_item, multi_id) in enumerate(zip(sample_df['single_item_list'],sample_df['multi_item_list'],sample_df['multi_id'])):
    if (any(isinstance(i, list) for i in multi_item)) == False:
        for j, item_list in enumerate(multi_item):
            if single[0] in item_list:
                pos = item_list.index(single[0])
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_item_list'] = [item_list]
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_id'] = [multi_id[j]]
    else:
        print("under nested list")
        for j, item_list in enumerate(zip(multi_item,multi_id)):
            if single[0] in multi_item[j]:
                pos = multi_item[j].index(single[0])
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_item_list'][j] = single[0]
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_id'][j] = multi_id[j][pos]
            else:
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_item_list'][j] = np.nan
                sample_df.at[i,'multi_id'][j] = np.nan
```

But this assigns NA to the whole column value. I expect to remove that specific list (within a nested list).

I expect my output to be like as below:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have something like: `[['QWER12, FAS324], 'ABC123', ['DEF456']]`?

Comment: may I ask from where did you get `[['QWER12, FAS324], 'ABC123', ['DEF456']]`? I don't see this in my input dataframe

Comment: I asked if it was possible to have something different than the example shown. All your use cases are here: a list of strings and a list of list of strings?

Comment: yes, possible to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the data it looks like removing duplicates is equivalent to keeping the first element in any list of lists while any standard lists are kept as they are. If this is true, then you can solve it as follows:

```py
def get_first_list(x):
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
        return [x[0]]
    return x

for c in ['multi_item_list', 'multi_id']:
    sample_df[c] = sample_df[c].apply(get_first_list)
```

Result:

```
  single_proj_name single_item_list single_id           multi_proj_name                  multi_item_list                   multi_id
0           [jsfk]        [ABC_123]    [1234]         [AAA, VVVV, SASD]        [[XYZAV, ADS23, ABC_123]]      [[2167, 2147, 29481]]
1           [fhjk]         [DEF123]    [5678]  [QEWWQ, SFA, JKKK, fhjk]  [XYZAV, DEF123, ABC_123, SAJKF]  [2313, 57567, 2321, 7898]
2           [ERRW]         [FAS324]   [91011]              [ERRW, TTTT]                 [QWER12, FAS324]               [1123, 8775]
3          [SJBAK]        [HSJD123]  [121314]             [SJBAK, YYYY]              [[JFAJKA, HSJD123]]            [[5237, 43512]]
```

---

To handle the case where there can be more than a single unique list the `get_first_list` method can be adjusted to:

```py
def get_first_list(x):
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
        new_x = []
        for i in x:
            if i not in new_x:
                new_x.append(i)
        return new_x
    return x
```

This will keep the order of the sublists while removing any sublist duplicates.

Comment: Appreciate your effort. But there could be 3 sub-lists (within a main list) and they might occur as 2nd and 3rd items. In that case, the above logic may not work I guess

Comment: @TheGreat: That's correct, I added an adjusted method that can handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly with [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) function:

```
cols = ['multi_item_list', 'multi_id']
sample_df[cols] = sample_df[cols].apply(lambda x: [np.unique(a, axis=0) if type(a[0]) == list else a for a in x.values])
```

---

```
In [382]: sample_df
Out[382]: 
  single_proj_name single_item_list single_id           multi_proj_name  \
0           [jsfk]        [ABC_123]    [1234]         [AAA, VVVV, SASD]   
1           [fhjk]         [DEF123]    [5678]  [QEWWQ, SFA, JKKK, fhjk]   
2           [ERRW]         [FAS324]   [91011]              [ERRW, TTTT]   
3          [SJBAK]        [HSJD123]  [121314]             [SJBAK, YYYY]   

                   multi_item_list                   multi_id  
0        [[XYZAV, ADS23, ABC_123]]      [[2167, 2147, 29481]]  
1  [XYZAV, DEF123, ABC_123, SAJKF]  [2313, 57567, 2321, 7898]  
2                 [QWER12, FAS324]               [1123, 8775]  
3              [[JFAJKA, HSJD123]]            [[5237, 43512]]
```